# Bootstrap modal pushing content up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have been working with the bootstrap modal for the past few hours and I'm having some trouble. I searched all over the place, but couldn't find anyone with a similar issue.

My modal looks like this

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything else works, and the modal itself works, but whenever I click the button the containing div just ignores it's margin-top and goes to the top of the page. I'm hoping it is something stupid that I've done.

Edit: Here is the CSS I'm using for this page. I forgot to mention that the modal above is on a page with datatables, which together are an iframe for another page. After I click to open the modal, the div that is containing the iframe goes to the top of the page as well.

```
.container{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

a, a:hover {
  color: #6a6e4d;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pagination>.active>a, .pagination>.active>span, .pagination>.active>a:hover,
.pagination>.active>span:hover, .pagination>.active>a:focus,
.pagination>.active>span:focus {
  background-color: #6a6e4d;
  border-color: #6a6e4d;
}
```

Comment: Either paste whole html file, or make a fiddle. Cannot make out anything from here ...

Comment: @Jesse your code is incomplete by looking at your css bro

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I cant understand that much from above code. 
I think your modal popup is ignoring margin-top css rule.
Add below css into your page and change **padding-top** parameter.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
.modal-dialog {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  width: 600px;
  padding-top: 130px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps dropping the top:10px might work in the css for container.